# What's the difference between this two version on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I saw two versions for download on Node.js main page as below

Which one should I use and What's the difference?

[image]

Comment: Read the changelogs - looks like the v4 is stable and v6 has some more experimental features

Comment: Did you try a basic Google search before posting here?  This question is asked a lot and there are many detailed descriptions of what the different levels/versions of node.js mean.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for LTS. LTS stands for long term support.

`https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_support`

Answer (score 0):

On their website, they have a pretty decent (brief) list of changes from v5 to the current version v6.2.2.  https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v6.0.0/

If you're planning on deploying your project in a production environment, stick with the LTS (Long Term Support) version.  Otherwise feel free to use the latest version.

When the next odd-numbered version is released, the previous even-numbered version becomes LTS.  v6.x.x will become LTS in October, 2016 with the release of Node v7 according to Node's LTS plan.